# popup window notification after submit

Tags: javascript

I have a form with several fileds to be filled and I would like to open a popup window after the user has correctly filled the form

To start, I do not know why this simple line of code does not work

```
<form>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="javascript:alert('success');" />

</form>
```

I have checked that the user is correctly created so it means that the submit was OK but I did not get the alert window

Could you explain ?

Comment: `onsubmit` is an attribute for `<form>` not `<input>`. Also keep in mind `onsubmit` happens before the request been sent, not after the response.

Comment: What pop up window? Like modal pop up? http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: Hi Alek, just a normal window saying is was OK

Comment: @stackSaru: by *normal*, I think you mean, [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers more the first part of your question, pertaining to how you might interact with the user following the submission of a form, which you may also want to validate. It does not answer your more specific question as to: "why does the `onsubmit` not work?" For that answer, there are several other excellent answers (specifically [Canon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23635050/657674) citing the improper location of the `onsubmit` attribute.

With that out of the way...

Depending on the type of user interaction you want, after submitting the form, you may be interested in looking into XHR (XMLHttpRequest) with JavaScript. You can do this in pure JavaScript without a library, but if you want a nice, tried-and-true, way of handling the request and responses in an asynchronous manner I would look into the jQuery library, specifically either the [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

jQuery will allow you to do things before and after you submit the form. If you want to validate the form's content before you send it to the server, you can do so. jQuery will also give you the ability to react to successful, failed, and "always" interactions based on the responses you get back from the server so you can better tailor the user experience you want for your users.

Below is a very simple example that shows how you could serialize the form and post it to the URL (in the example below the URL defined in the `action` attribute on the `form`) and receive a response back. You can then handle that response, if it is JSON or XML/HTML, however you need to.

```
$('form').submit(function(/*DOMEvent*/ e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = $(this).attr('action'),
      data = $(this).serialize();
  $.post(url, data, function(response){
    /* Do something with the response, here we'll just log it to the console */
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Again, this is only a simple example.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks a lot for your answer, my main problem now is that when I click on the input, there is a validation code in Java behind the scene that makes the verifications, and when I use onsubmit, well the message "sucess" is displayed even if a field is missing. Well, maybe I can open a different question.

Comment: @stackSaru You're welcome, I know it wasn't exactly the answer to the specific question you were asking, but I thought it worth mentioning given the context and spirit of the question. Although, I think Canon's answer may be the more "correct" answer for your specific question, though.

Comment: @stackSaru: it would probably be better to edit this question to make it more specific.

Comment: @canon the question I was answering was less about "why doesn't [my] `onsubmit` work" and more about answering the more abstract question he began with, in the context of (paraphrased) "how do I show a popup [window] after [validating] the user filled the form correctly." I made this more clear at the start of my answer (hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

From MDN's documentation of the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit) event (emphasis mine)

> The `submit` event is fired when a form is submitted.
>   
> Note that **`submit` is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input**. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

So, move your `submit` handler from the `<input>` to the `<form>` ([sample](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/pEuy4/)):

```
<form onsubmit="alert('success');">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

<sub>Note: Keep in mind that this alert will appear before the form is actually submitted... thereby blocking submission (and everything else) until the alert is dismissed.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`onsubmit` should be on the form tag, not the input. If you really want to put something there, it's `onclick` you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following `POSTS` the form data to a jsp page, and check's the returned response.  If the jsp page returns the string `success` the success message will be displayed.

```
<script>
    function checkit(){
        $.post( "ajax/test.jsp",
            $('#form').serialize(),
            function( data ) {
            if(data == "success"){
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<form onsubmit='checkit()' id="form">
    <input type='text' id="txt" />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The alert doenst popup because you submit the form. So it never reach there.

Its good for you to add more code. So assuming you are doing this in PHP (The form processor), you should add that alert there. Like this:

```
<?php
If($queryThatStoreTheUser){
?>
<script>
alert('Success');
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Of course this is just assuming it. onsubmit will not work in that situation.

Grettings