# message after form validation

Tags: java, javascript

I have a JSP page which has several input fields and a servlet validates the fields when I click on the submit button and redirects to another page.

I would like to add a popup window: "all the fields are ok" after a correct *server-side* validation.

So I started with:

```
<form ="alert('success');">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that "success" is printed even if the fields are incorrect.

I thought about setting a parameter in the 
protected void `doPost(HttpServletRequest` request,`HttpServletResponse` response, which calls an execute() function to say if things are OK or not but I do not know how to get this parameter just after the submit so I could make a conditional:

```
if (checkSubmitParameter == OK )
   callsPopup()
```

Comment: You'll need to include some actual code; as posted nothing makes any sense and it's impossible to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of OP's other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634995/popup-window-notification-after-submit/23635290#23635290

Comment: where is your validation happens ? seems you are doing validation in servlet ? why ? cant you do it in client side it self ? if you do it in servlet you cant achieve the behavior you wanted in normal HTTPRequest . you might need to submit XmlHttpRequest

Comment: Hi theed, it is actually about the same part of code but I wanted to separate the issues and that my questions to be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Q2N/)):

```
<script>
function checkit(){
    var val = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    if(val == "good"){
        alert("success");
    }else{
        alert("failure!");
    }
}    
</script>
<form onsubmit='checkit()'>
    <input type='text' id="txt" />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```